# Creating views at runtime using spring data / jpa

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

In my project we are creating views dynamically using some naming strategy such as

view_123,view_456

```
Statement statment = connection.createStatement();
viewQueryForNode="CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW JGM_VIEW1"
try {
    connection.setAutoCommit(true);
    statment.executeUpdate(viewQueryForNode);
}finally {
    statment.close();
    connection.close();
}
```

Now my question is how to map this dynamic view to Jpa entities, so that i can use spring data repositories to read this view.

Note: the views are getting created with different names and destroyed dynamically at run time.

Comment: That's not possible.

Comment: is there a better way of reading view data apart from ResultSet ?

Comment: The problem is that you are creating it dynamically and JPA/Hibernate is static. So SQL with ResultSet is the only way to read this data.

Comment: It might be possible using a NamingStrategy, which determines the correct view name for each entity to use.

Comment: But the real question is: Why would you do that?

Comment: we are creating a network(oracle ndm) with the help of node_view and link_view, creating so many networks like this, as per the user request,hence so many views getting created at runtime.